# Flash vs. Silverlight vs. HTML5

Tags: flash

I am going to develop a video sharing (for certain types of videos & open to public) site.
I am planning to use Sorenson squeeze than FFMPEG for processing. Anyone has other options?

These are some basic requirements:

**My app is a .NET app. So you might think go with Silverlight. But I want to use the best one

Quality of video when played has to be best
Smallest size for the deployment package/files
Ease of player customizations + Rich API
Videos should play smoothly on pc and mobile devices w/o much extra plugins
Good streaming support
Support in all OS (Linux? Yes)
Support HD

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest, you pick a main market first, and then implement the app in the way, that is fastest and easiest and will work for your target audience. Once the app's online, and people are using it, then you can create additional clients to expand.
For example, you might say, you're fine with PC and Mac users, you don't care for linux or mobile devices and go with flash. If the user reception is good, then the users will tell you, where they want you to go next. Will they cry out for iPhone support? Will they say "app's great, but flash sucks"? Who knows.

Don't try do build a software that runs perfect on all platform. That **never** works. Build a server, build one client that works perfectly on a set of platforms you choose beforehand and then ask your self, which other platforms are worth the effort of a port.

Personally, I think flash is the best choice. As of now, it has the highest market penetration among your options. And it's easy to roll your own player, but even if you don't want to, there are tons of open source and commercial solutions.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 1):

None of the Above are going to be a sliver bullet for you.  HTML5 is still in flux and not fully implemented, let alone has the browser share of HTML5 compliant versions of browsers hit the butter zone.  Silverlight kicks to the curb some of your users, and Flash is hit or miss on linux.

If i was in your shoes, i'd go Flash or HTML5.  Browsers will be updating soonish, but Flash, for all it's wonderful horrible faults, is still pretty "solid" from an end user presentation perspective.

Comment: I will drop HTML5 from my options. I am worried if flash will be killed by Apple and MSFT

Comment: Flash aint going anywhere anytime soon.  Unfortuneately.  Anyone who says otherwise is trying to sell you something.

Comment: @Projapti - it is always possible, but unlikely. Apple, and a lot of people are keen to see it die. A vast majority are just on the bandwagon and don't have a clue about the strengths and weaknesses. Flash is actually pretty good, there is nothing nasty or horrible about it - certainly beats developing in JavaScript.

Comment: @Projapati: Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about that. It definitely will not disappear before the first rewrite of your app ;) If you care, I made a quite lengthy post on why I think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643407/should-web-developers-learn-flash/2644910#2644910

Comment: Thanks folks. This is confusing for no reason.
I don't want to be in limbo situation where I go with one technology and later I have to re-encode all videos to another format.

I hope you understand my concerns.

I haven't done any flash programming even though I am a .net developer

Answer (score 0):

It's way to early for HTML5. Screw Linux, at least if you don't provide beard related products. If you want to support Linux keep in mind Silverlight 1 + 2: ok with Moonlight (I'd rather have Moonshine), Silverlight 3+: Maybe in a few years. If your main goal is streaming HD videos, give the DIVX WebPlayer a chance. Quality is top.

[DivX](http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus/web-player)

Comment: My main goal is NOT streaming HD videos
I want to let users upload HD videos

Comment: Ok, so you got a upload handler.. ashx or something like that.. in the background, in the frontend I would serve the user a silverlight upload component, if no silverlight is detected, load a flash component, if neither flash or silverlight are detected, serve a simple html upload form.

Comment: Uploader component is independent from the player.
Uploader dumps the raw video to queue. The engine will process the file (with conversion) and publish it.
That published file will be played by the player.